# Missing type of result? In function length :: Monad m => ByteString m r -> m (Of Int r)

Tags: haskell, haskell-streaming

I have a simple function that reads a binary file one byte at a time. It get a compile time error, below. The problem seems to be that `bs2`, the resulting ByteString of [`BSSC.length`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-bytestring-0.1.6/docs/Data-ByteString-Streaming-Char8.html#v:length), has an unknown type. Am I missing a type constraint on `r`?

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Streaming.Char8 as BSSC

main :: IO ()
main = runResourceT $ dump $ BSSC.readFile "filename"

dump :: (MonadIO m) => BSSC.ByteString m r -> m ()                                                                                                                                                
dump bs = do
    len :> bs2 <- BSSC.length bs          -- Data.Functor.Of (:>)
    if len <= 1 then return ()
    else dump $ BSSC.putStr $ BSSC.splitAt 1 bs2
```

Compile-time error:

```
Main.hs:166:46: error:
  • Couldn't match expected type ‘BSSC.ByteString
                                    (BSSC.ByteString m) r0’
                with actual type ‘r’
    ‘r’ is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for:
        dump :: forall (m :: * -> *) r.
                MonadIO m =>
                BSSC.ByteString m r -> m ()
      at Main.hs:162:9
  • In the second argument of ‘BSSC.splitAt’, namely ‘bs2’
    In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘BSSC.splitAt 1 bs2’
    In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
      ‘BSSC.putStr $ BSSC.splitAt 1 bs2’
  • Relevant bindings include
      bs2 :: r (bound at Main.hs:164:12)
      bs :: BSSC.ByteString m r (bound at Main.hs:163:6)
      dump :: BSSC.ByteString m r -> m () (bound at Main.hs:163:1)
```

Comment: Your problem that in `len :> bs2 <- BSSC.length bs` `bs2` is not content (not even `ByteString`), but just `()`. If you want to operate with `ByteString` it is looks like you can't extract value out of it, use `if` and continue to use `ByteString`.

Comment: If you want to recursive process your string you have to use `uncons` to get head and tail, and do recursive call with tail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ByteString` type from streaming-bytestring has two type parameters. The first is the base monad `m` in which the values are produced (typically `IO`).

The second is a special ending value `r` that is  returned once the `ByteString` is exhausted. Usually it will be an uninformative `()`. However, it becomes very useful for defining functions like `splitAt :: Monad m => Int64 -> ByteString m r -> ByteString m (ByteString m r)`. The type means: "give me a limit position and a effectful stream of bytes that returns with an `r`, I will give you another stream that is no longer than the limit and returns with a effectful stream of bytes that returns with an `r`." This ending stream nested within the outer one can only be reached after the outer one is exhausted.

`length` has type `Monad m => ByteString m r -> m (Of Int r)`. It consumes the stream of values it receives as argument and returns an action in the base monad. The `ByteString` exists no more. The `bs2` that you pass to `splitAt` is not a `ByteString` but the ending value of the original `ByteString`, which has type `r`. And this causes a type error.

Answer (score 0):

You can hotfix type mismatch with using `bs` as second parameter to `splitAt`

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Streaming.Char8 as BSSC

main :: IO ()
main = runResourceT $ dump $ BSSC.readFile "filename"

dump :: (MonadIO m) => BSSC.ByteString m r -> m ()                                                                                                                                                
dump bs = do
    len :> bs2 <- BSSC.length bs
    if len <= 1 then return ()
    else dump $ BSSC.putStr $ BSSC.splitAt 1 bs
```

but it won't work as you expect. I guess it will read file as many times as many letter in it.

If you want recursion you should go with

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Streaming.Char8 as BSSC

main :: IO ()
main = runResourceT $ dump $ BSSC.readFile "filename"

dump :: (MonadIO m) => BSSC.ByteString m r -> m ()                                                                                                                                                
dump bs = do
    split <- BSSC.uncons bs
    case split of
       Left _        -> return ()
       Right (x, xs) -> putStr (show x) >> dump xs
```

I don't have compiler with me, so it is possibly there are compilation prblems in my snippets.